# combine multiple columns read.csv in r

Tags: r

IS there a way to combine multiple columns into a single column while reading data from csv files.

Example

My data in file is in below format
ID,DOB,FirstName,LastName,DOJ

In read.csv/read.table is it possible to convert this into a four column, where First and Last names are combined to get a new column called Name.

Comment: You can use `?paste` to combine the columns

Comment: I want to do it while reading. Actually my data set contains 1 GB file. Doing it after reading into memory is taking time. is there a way i can do it while reading, like in read.csv or read.table

Comment: see http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-large-tables.html for good tips for reading in large files

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with the `sqldf` package eg:

```
require(sqldf)

# Example Data
df <- data.frame(
  ID  = 1:5,
  DOB = 1:5,
  FirstName = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  LastName = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  DOJ = 1:5)

# Write to disc to load it afterwards
write.csv(df, "example.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

# Using SQL to combine ...
sql <- "Select ID, DOB, FirstName || ' ' || LastName as Name from file"
out <- read.csv.sql("example.csv", sql = sql)
out
# ID DOB Name
# 1  1   1  a A
# 2  2   2  b B
# 3  3   3  c C
# 4  4   4  d D
# 5  5   5  e E
```